# cordova-plugin-ms-adal issues with chrome version 83+

Tags: adal

I encountered some issues with cordova-plugin-ms-adal after the latest google chrome update (83), i assume the issues comes from the OOR-CORS update which they made on the chrome webview.
When i call `app.authContext.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUrl, appId, redirectUrl)`, the promise is never resolved and i think that the response from Azure AAD is blocked somewhere.

I don't see any errors related to CORS and i also can't find how to update my app in order to be OOR-CORS compliant. 
Anyone is experiencing the same issue? (any chrome under 83 works as expected).

**Updated:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The thing that is refreshing is the create context method which will be called twice, one time when i enter the page and second time when i'm refreshing the same page. (This fixes the adal blocked response)

When i'm calling the app.authContext.acquireTokenAsync it will never receive any response from AD until i do the first page reload, after that it will always work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to identify the issue, I would suggest you to look at the networks calls made with a chrome browser under 83 and compare it with chrome browser 83. The aim is to look for any difference in the response returned due to CORS headers etc. This might help you identify what has changed due to which promise is not resolved.

Since there is no CORS error being shown in console, I expect the response of the api is affected due to CORS implementation.

Another suggestion is to use adal-for-js ([link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js)) instead of adal-for-cordava ([link](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-cordova#readme)) as the later is depcreated and not maintained any more. Any bug fixes which could affect newer browser would require you to patch it directly which could be cumbersome effort, IMO.

Comment: Looking at documentaiton of what went live in chrome 83 for webview (https://dev.chromium.org/Home/loading/oor-cors), I don't see anything immediately which should affect it but there should be some sideeffect of one the change which is not directly visible.

Comment: I was looking over that doc and could not find something relevant either, i will try to use adal for js instead of adal for cordova, thanks for your response :)

Comment: If this solves your problem, can you voteup and accept the answer :-)

Comment: It solved it somehow, but i have some troubles with the redirect URI, as i understood the redirectURI should match the location where UserAgentApplication is created in order for login popups to close otherwise they remain open, and the problem is that on device it will try to navigate to that redirect uri which will crash the application. Something i found out is when i am refreshing the app, the adal for cordova works again. It does not work until i do one location.reload();

Comment: If possible, can you share a sample with problem? it is difficult for me to understand why location.reload is needed as ideally that should not be needed for it to work.

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots, i did not found any reason why the location works because the same thing is called again after the reload.

Comment: Do you see 'Created authentication context for authority' log twice? If so, this is definitely some issue in async processing model in new chrome which is affecting it. I can't think of why this is the case here yet.
On side note, I would suggest you to try adal-for-js as this library is not maintain which could cause issues in future releases of browsers.

Comment: I see it twice yes, we will switch to adal-for-js library and that should work fine, thanks for your help :)